# Problems when trying to decode an mpeg stream

Tags: video, video-streaming, mpeg, avconv

I have an MPEG stream sent to me on UDP.
I use the following avconv command to read it:
`avconv -i udp://<some_ip_address>:8000 output.ts`

I'm getting many errors, for example:

```
[mpegts @ 0x21df040] Continuity check failed for pid 414 expected 2 got 6
[eac3 @ 0x239d840] new coupling strategy must be present in block
[eac3 @ 0x239d840] error decoding the audio block
```

The avconv metadata as printed by avconv is:
    Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://224.1.1.1:8000':
      Duration: N/A, start: 60422.123044, bitrate: 576 kb/s
      Program 146
        Metadata:
          service_name    : BLABLA
          service_provider:
        Stream #0.0[0x19e]: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
        Stream #0.1[0x194]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 448 kb/s
        Stream #0.2[0x195]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
        Stream #0.3[0x1b2]: Data: [134][0][0][0] / 0x0086

One more important detail is that if I just copy the udp stream using avconv `codec copy` to a local file and then use the exact avconv command to decode this file, everything goes smoothly, and I see no errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the errors don't halt the encoding, then you should be good just ignoring them. It is fairly normal to see warnings like that when reading network streams.

You can try adding the `-re` option to force real time encoding and see if that helps.

Also, I'm assuming that your CPU has plenty of power for this---if not, that could cause problems and result in a lot of errors/warnings/video glitches.